# Ray dashboard unavailable on local cluster

Tags: python, ray

I am having a lot of problems with Ray due to show the dashboard. I'm just using Ray Core to parallelize tasks as you can see:

```sh
$ pipenv --python 3.9 shell
$ pip --version
pip 22.0.2 from .../lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

$ pip install -U ray
Collecting ray
  Using cached ray-1.12.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (52.9 MB)
```

```sh
$ ray start --head --dashboard-host 0.0.0.0 --dashboard-port 8265
Usage stats collection will be enabled by default in the next release. See https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/20857 for more details.
Local node IP: 192.168.1.49

--------------------
Ray runtime started.
--------------------

Next steps
  To connect to this Ray runtime from another node, run
    ray start --address='192.168.1.49:6379'
  
  Alternatively, use the following Python code:
    import ray
    ray.init(address='auto')
  
  To connect to this Ray runtime from outside of the cluster, for example to
  connect to a remote cluster from your laptop directly, use the following
  Python code:
    import ray
    ray.init(address='ray://<head_node_ip_address>:10001')
  
  If connection fails, check your firewall settings and network configuration.
  
  To terminate the Ray runtime, run
    ray stop
```

```
$ python                                                         
Python 3.9.12 (main, Mar 24 2022, 13:02:21) 
[GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ray
>>> ray.init(address='auto')
RayContext(dashboard_url='', python_version='3.9.12', ray_version='1.12.0', ray_commit='f18fc31c7562990955556899090f8e8656b48d2d', address_info={'node_ip_address': '192.168.1.49', 'raylet_ip_address': '192.168.1.49', 'redis_address': None, 'object_store_address': '/tmp/ray/session_2022-05-16_07-48-29_657710_74480/sockets/plasma_store', 'raylet_socket_name': '/tmp/ray/session_2022-05-16_07-48-29_657710_74480/sockets/raylet', 'webui_url': '', 'session_dir': '/tmp/ray/session_2022-05-16_07-48-29_657710_74480', 'metrics_export_port': 56749, 'gcs_address': '192.168.1.49:6379', 'address': '192.168.1.49:6379', 'node_id': '449661c0bd0c354f09739309f42ac73e7593b4870fed8712d5a6a0e7'})
```

And localhost:8265 is not shown. I've already tried changing to another port, deploying cluster on Azure, using last commit Ray package... but dashboard is not shown anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Dashboard requires different installation (see [docs](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/ray-dashboard.html)):

`pip install -U ray[default]`

Comment: The command missing double quotes.